# Difference between request and query?

Tags: javascript, express

I'm learning a bit of Javascript and mongodb , actually i installed ExpressJS which have .request , and QueryStringParser modulles which have .query . Which is the difference between both?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which QueryStringParser modules did you installed, but since you already mention MongoDB I assume you are talking about this https://github.com/diegohaz/querymen

Expres `request` handles the HTTP requests while Querymen's `query` is an Express middleware to build a MongoDB query from parameters in the HTTP querystring request nothing else.

You can read more about both in the following links

- https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req
- https://github.com/diegohaz/querymen